# How to enable autocomplete for a search input box depending upon a category dropdown value?

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete

I have situation like below:

[image: Page]

The textbox is now a open search box and the select box is a dropdown with different values; now the scenario is to enable autocomplete for couple of category values

So how to manage the autocomplete enabling and other categories as open search and not autocomplete.

We are using AngularJS 1.x in our application as the base framework.

Answer (score 0):

use anguComplete module for autocomplete,when ever you want autocomplete code than you push the data into countries array the relative data to the autocomplete,if you are not interested than you don't push the data into countries array  in to that array.

Comment: `<div angucomplete-alt id="ex1"
  placeholder="Search countries"
  maxlength="50"
  pause="100"
  selected-object="selectedCountry"
  local-data="countries"`
  `search-fields="name"
  title-field="name"`
  minlength="1"`
  input-class="form-control form-control-small"
  match-class="highlight"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Easy way, add angularjs material that contains directive [mdAutocomplete](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.5/api/directive/mdAutocomplete) . It's already contains a lot of possible options that you could need in future.

Comment: How to use it conditionally as explained in the question above? @QuP